# How do I deploy a VB.Net app with latest update to VB

Tags: vb.net, publishing

I am new to VB.Net. I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2019. I am trying to learn it using a book based on that edition but, I think, an earlier version.  In the chapter on deploying an app it gives a sequence of actions which result in the familiar setup.exe file.  Following a similar sequence with the latest version results in 5 files; appname.exe, appname.dll, appname.pdb, appname.deps.json and appname.runtimeconfig.json.  What do I need to do to generate a single setup.exe file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from the "app" project, you will need a separate "installer" project. Or just copy those generated files, that should also work

Comment: The book is old, VS no longer has built-in support for installer projects.  It can still be [downloaded](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects).  It is doubtful that the book recommended you'd create a .NETCore project btw, select a project template with ".NET Framework" in the template name to avoid confusion.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2019

Comment: [Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension and .NET 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019) -- Note that the examples refer to .Net Core 3.1 and a WPF app, but it's the same in case you have, e.g., a Windows Forms app and .Net 5, just pick the correct .Net versions from the selectors, as shown in the sample images.

Comment: Many thanks - just what I needed.